# When Node js and react are used in a project at the same time, does server side rendering happen? I'm new to this

Tags: javascript, node.js

When Node js and react are used in a project at the same time, does server side rendering happen? I'm new to this. that is, pages such as (about, contact) are created with react and then the server is written by node js and when the request is received, pages such as about, contact are directed to the user, so this is the process when using react with node?

Comment: No. For server side rendering to happen, you still need to write code (that does use react.js on node) that instructs the server to render the page.

Comment: Are This pages must write on node js?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that sentence. If you have trouble with the language, maybe [one of the localised StackOverflow versions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322314/1048572) suits you better?

Comment: You may want to google "reactjs server side rendering" to learn more about what it is and how to make one first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When Node js and react are used in a project at the same time, does server side rendering happen?

Maybe, but not necessarily.

If you have a React project with SSR then you almost certainly will be using Node.js (probably with the Next.js framework) to perform the SSR.

However, you could have an application without SRR that used Node.js at runtime (e.g. to provide a webservice) and any React application is likely to use Node.js at build-time (e.g. to run Babel and Webpack to prepare the application for deployment).

Comment: In theory you can also do SSR without React on the server, in any language, and just hydrate the html with React. But without using the same component code, it likely won't work very well.

Comment: @Bergi — Well yes, hence "almost certainly" :)

Answer (score -3):

When Nodejs server and React  are running at same time,
If there are 2 pages About.js and Contact.js
[About page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BZ5v.png)

About page is accessed through REACT-ROUTER-DOM and likewise Contact page is also through REACT-ROUTER-DOM.
About.js

[React main page for routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aS5T.png) and continuation part([react routing continuation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1C2u.png)
THIS IS THE NODEJS SERVER BELOW

By getting
[Nodejs generate about contact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey5E0.png)
[Nodejs code link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4Wsb.png)

So after that we will place this local application programming interface in react components by given below

[react code link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acqtr.png)
So in this page I have used AXIOS to fetch the data from the application programming interface
NPM INSTALL AXIOS in react and it would be blocked by CORS Policy to avoid that we can install NPM INSTALL CORS and require it in NODEJS server.
Now I am running the server together and using react hooks I am able to get the data passed from application programming interface
About page and contact page.

Comment: Please post code as text with syntax highlighting, not links to paintings of it